# recovering lost Google chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome

Normally when Google Chrome closes it saves my tabs and when I re-open Google Chrome all my tabs are restored. But it doesn't do that all the time.

I don't suppose there's any way to get those tabs back? I could look through my browser history but just because I visited a website yesterday or the day before or whatever doesn't mean I had an open tab to it.

I mean, if my computer was shut off unexpectedly I could understand why it wouldn't save the tabs, but half of the time Chrome fails to save tabs for something like Windows Automatic Updates.

Comment: That is a bit strange, this only happens to me because of user (me) error, or because of an evil WIFI gateway that hijacks all my tabs. Normally my tabs are saved even when I kill the process.

Comment: I use XMarks to prevent this behavior. Once the cache file is lost its cannot be recovered.  Which is the reason I sync my open tabs to XMarks.

Comment: What does the 'Recently Closed' pop up on the new tab page show?

Answer (score 2):

You can view these tabs via the "Recent Tabs" menu under the drop-down menu.  It all stays synced through your account, so closed tabs from all instances of Chrome will be available.  I believe this is all retained until the browser history itself gets cleared (not automatically from computer reboot).